# How to debug GXT application and how to print error message on browser console for debugging?

Tags: java, spring, debugging, gwt, gxt

I am woring on a project where i have to debug gxt files on UI and want to print few error message on chrome console.  What to write in GXT java file to print messages on console.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to debug a GTX application, like every other GWT application, is using Super Dev Mode (SDM).

See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wxlh_E8uyq4

To print something on the browser's console, you can use `GWT.log("debug message");` or `DomGlobal.console.log("debug message");`.

Hope that helps.